# Image stretch 100% of screen resolution

Tags: width, resolution, stretch

I thought I would have found the answer to this question long ago, but I just can't seem to find it anywhere and I'm wondering if you could please help.

Put simply, I want an image to stretch (width only) to 100% of the monitor screen resolution.

Here's what I've tried....

style="position:absolute;width:100%"
This simply makes the image 100% the width of its original size.

style="width:100%"
This makes the image stretch to 100% of the website area (in my case 960px). This is not what I want, as I need the image to stretch 100% of the entire monitor resolution.

style="position:fixed;width:100%"
This makes the image stretch to 100% of the monitor area (yay!) but the fixed position of the image causes problems for the webpage. I'd prefer the image was absolute.

Any information you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What happens if the user has two monitors with different resolutions? What if the browser window is half one monitor and half on the other? You should describe the problem you actually want to solve, not the technical issues you have with the solution you think is correct.

Comment: Dumbfounded by the response here, particularly 'you should describe the problem you actually want solved'.
Let me put this another way - I want the image to stretch 100% the width of the browser window. So if the window is set to the full monitor size, then the image should stretch to 100% of that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [100% width of browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942481/100-width-of-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Put the image in a div and set that div to 100% then set the width of that image to 100% however wouldn't this just stretch the image?

Comment: I looking to expand a simple coloured box, so stretching it won't destroy the image quality.

How might the code look for something like that? I've been tinkering but having difficulty.

Comment: Just set a div to 100% if the width and then set the background-colour?